# Adding a metabox on a CPT's submenu page

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox

I have a custom post type registered and a submenu page for some admin actions for  the CPT. This page has some items listed in a WP table. I want to add a meta box just below those items. This is what I have currently.

```
//show-trollers is the slug for the sub menu page
add_action("load-troll-cpt_page_show-trollers", "troll_add_metaboxes");
function troll_add_metaboxes() {
    //Works, I can see the message at the top of the dashboard
    echo "Called";
    add_meta_box("troll-metabox", "My Troll Metabox", "display_troll_metabox", "troll-cpt", "normal", "core");
}

//This isn't working
function display_troll_metabox() {
    echo "Metabox"; 
}
```

Any reason why the metabox callback doesn't work?

**Update:**
I found out I had to call 'do_meta_boxes' so that the metaboxes are rendered. Now the issue is that the metabox appears on the top of the page, outside everything. How do I fix that?

This is my latest code:

```
add_action("load-troll-cpt_page_show-trollers", "troll_add_metaboxes");
function troll_add_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box("troll-metabox", "My Troll Metabox", "display_troll_metabox", "troll-menu-page", "normal", "core");
    do_meta_boxes('troll-menu-page', 'normal', null);
}

function display_my_metabox() {
?>
     <div class="postbox">
       This is a meta box
      </div>
<?php 
}
```

Comment: add_meta_box() function must be called in 'add_meta_boxes' action, you are calling it on 'load-troll-cpt_page_show-trollers', try to call it on 'add_meta_boxes' action.

Comment: The 'add_meta_boxes' action is not called on custom pages. Besides, my current action works fine.

Comment: Where are you calling my_add_metaboxes() function?

Comment: It's a typo! Updating the question.